# Azure WebJob not passing arguments

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have a console app published to Azure as a web app with WebJob. The webjob properties list the webhook and it is running. I am testing with Postman and passing the argument(s) using the prescribed url query method. I get a 202 response, and the webjob log shows success, but I can see that no arguments are processed when the app is executed. This should be working, but it is not. My app works as a standalone executable from command line with arguments.

request url: `https://myapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/MyWebJob/run?arguments={my arguments}`

[WebJob Log Success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unmsB.png)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "no arguments are **processed**"? Do you mean that you don't see `WEBJOBS_COMMAND_ARGUMENTS` being set when your exe is launched?

Comment: You may also want to show some code to show people how you are attempting to access the query string arguments.

Comment: @DavidEbbo - I've added a screencap of the webjob log success message. The "No args" console message indicates that no arguments were passed into the run command. I added a no argument condition to my app to troubleshoot.

Comment: @DavidYates - Not really sure what you mean by "accessing" query string arguments. According to the WebJob SDK (https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API#invoke-a-triggered-job), they are supposed to be passed into the triggered app when the arguments key is set with a value. My app accepts up to three arguments, (including none for the purpose of troubleshooting.)

Comment: Did you check `WEBJOBS_COMMAND_ARGUMENTS` as per my previous comment?

Comment: [Postman Screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/dQCM3xN)
@DavidEbbo - Yes, I used the environment variable as seen in the postman screenshot. Same result when the app runs on trigger...no argument

Comment: I don't follow what you're doing in postman. `WEBJOBS_COMMAND_ARGUMENTS` is an environment variable that should contain the arguments that you can access in your WebJob. Did you try evaluating it to see if it was set>

Comment: @DavidEbbo - I figured out that I was using the "environment variable" attribute incorrectly in postman. I found the application setting variable section in the webjob settings and added one for `WEBJOBS_COMMAND_ARGUMENTS`; value = "TEST". I removed the query parameter from the http POST and tested again. Still no arguments being passed by the webjob to the application when executed. I have worked around the issue by creating a primary use case condition in my console app that does not take any arguments. I can now use this in the scheduler without issue.

Comment: You are misunderstanding how this works. You need to pass arguments in the query string. Then **within your WebJobs code**, you should be able to access the value of those arguments by evaluating `WEBJOBS_COMMAND_ARGUMENTS`. Did you try that?

Comment: I'd still like to get arguments working though, if possible. I have several functions I would like to perform using my app, and schedule them to execute automatically. I'd like to know why it is that the kudu documentation for passing arguments to the application webjob via an http POST query parameter not working.

Comment: I think I found your problem. See my answer.

Comment: Ah! so you are suggesting that in my console app, I should be evaluating the `WEBJOBS_COMMAND_ARGUMENTS` environment variable instead of the args array? I will set the environment variable value to empty in the azure app settings and  pass the arguments in the post query string. That will set the environment variable value to the argument query string? If so, I will give that a shot and report back with the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are using a `run.cmd` that does not flow the command line arguments. Try changing it to:

```
ShipstationTest.exe %*
```

Comment: This webjob run.cmd is created automatically when publishing the console app as a webjob using VS2017. I do not see how I can access the webjob code in this instance to make the change you are suggesting.

Comment: As a test, try manually changing it in kudu console to see if that in fact works. If so, we can then worry about how to deploy it from VS

Comment: As an aside, I just did a clean WebJobs deployment test from VS and I did not end up with a `run.cmd` at all.

Comment: Thank you sir, that just saved me a lot of problems!